# python parsing for file to file and output file

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a `py` script to parse a regshot file with items such as registries add and modified and parse it with a white list of known good registries to find any different registries. Then writing the different **values** to a text file in the exact form they shown in regshot `.txt` file.

ex:

> hklm\software\micrsoft\windows\currentversion\run\blahblah

How do I do this?

I'm not sure where to start and if I should use regular expressions.

Comment: What is a "good" registry? If you mean one starting with "hklm", you can use the *startswith* method of the str types. If a "good registry" ends with "blahblah", then... *endswith**. If it's "currentversion", you MAY be able to use *in* (check http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) Otherwise, you will probably have to use regular expressions

Comment: I would recommend not assuming everyone on here understands your source data formats and goals, and would suggest that you include some examples of what you are doing.

Comment: By regshot do you mean the output of this program? http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/

Comment: Right so I should have said by good registry i mean normal registries. Registries that are normally present. I have a document of known good registries like a white list. i want to compare it to a regshot output file to find any non white list registries.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions if your definitions of "known good registries" include classes of registry entries that can be expressed as regular expressions, for example: a registry_entry that matches all registry entries that include "currentversion" somewhere under "hklm\software\micrsoft\" could be defined as

```
re.match('^hklm\software\micrsoft\[^\\]*\currentversion', registry_entry)
```

Regular expressions are not needed if you only need to match a substring.  In that case, a simple "if x in y" will do, for example:

```
if 'hklm\software\micrsoft\' in registry_entry
```

If, however, your "known good registries" is simply a list of specific registry entries, then an even simpler match will do, for example:

```
registry_entries = [r'hklm\software\micrsoft\windows\currentversion\run\blahblah', r'hklm\software\micrsoft\windows\currentversion\skip\blahblah']
known_good_registries = [r'hklm\software\micrsoft\windows\currentversion\run\blahblah', r'hklm\software\micrsoft\windows\currentversion\jump\blahblah']

for entry in registry_entries:
    match = False
    if entry in known_good_registries:
        match = True
    if not match:
        print 'registry entry not in known good list: ', entry
```

Comment: A set would probably be far more efficient here.

Comment: okay so i can just match it to part of the registry to cut out stuff that doesnt matter like the if there is 3 runs